# Query Error when use pre-filtering CRMAF_

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-4

I have a query in SQL

```
    SELECT  ses_student.ses_studentId ,
    ses_student.ses_Student ,
    ses_student.ses_StudentName ,
    col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxID ,
    col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxNo ,
    col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxDate ,
    col_StudentInvoicePayments.Name ,
    col_StudentInvoicePayments.TotalAmount
FROM    ses_student AS CRMAF_ses_student
        INNER JOIN col_StudentInvoicePayments ON dses_student.ses_studentId = col_StudentInvoicePayments.ses_StudentId
```

It gives error 
multiple identifier ses_student.ses_studentId and ses_student.ses_Student

this error occur when I use pre filter "AS CRMAF_ses_student"
because it sis CRM DataBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this updated query....

```
SELECT  CRMAF_ses_student.ses_studentId ,
        CRMAF_ses_student.ses_Student ,
        CRMAF_ses_student.ses_StudentName ,
        col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxID ,
        col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxNo ,
        col_StudentInvoicePayments.TrxDate ,
        col_StudentInvoicePayments.Name ,
        col_StudentInvoicePayments.TotalAmount
FROM    ses_student AS CRMAF_ses_student
        INNER JOIN col_StudentInvoicePayments ON CRMAF_ses_student.ses_studentId = col_StudentInvoicePayments.ses_StudentId
```

Comment: but it not pre-filter record

Comment: @riaz.usmani Could you please let me explain what you need now..?

Comment: I run that report on Student Entity and want that it show only this student information. now, its shows information of all students.

Comment: @riaz.usmani To get particular student details you need to pass `ses_StudentID` in `where` clause.